# Resize JDialog by pushing it against the edge of the screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog, autoresize

I have a JFrame and a JDialog. The latter simply contains a JTextArea. Windows 7 gives now the possibility to resize a window to the half of the screen by pushing it against the right or the left edge. This works fine with the JFrame window. However, the JDialog window does not react to it, though it is manually resizable. I suppose it is closely connected with the missing maximize/minimize function of JDialogs. On the other hand, creating a JFrame as subframe is not recommended.

** Edit 1 **

Here a test code:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class JDialogResizetest extends JFrame {                  
    private JButton openButton;      

    public JDialogResizetest() {
        openButton = new JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        openButton.setText("Open");
        openButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                openButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(openButton);

        pack();
    }                       

    private void openButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(this, false);
        dialog.getContentPane().add(new JTextPane());
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }                                          

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JDialogResizetest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }            
}
```

Here a picture of the desired behavior:
[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the behavior you are seeing and then explain what you wanted to happen. It will help you get answers.

Comment: *"Does anyone has an idea how to solve this problem?"* What 'problem'?  Does Windows 7 allow other Windows (native) dialogs to resize that way?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I do not know and I could not find anything on this topic. Maybe my search terms were wrong. However, that would be maybe part of the answer of the question. Given the case that Windows 7 do not allow to resize JDialgo this way: Is it suitable to use a JFrame instead of a JDialog in this case? Given the case that Window allows resizability of JDialogs: How to do it?

Comment: *"Given the case that Windows 7 do not allow to resize JDialgo this way: Is it suitable.."*  No!  Don't try to break with the design philosophy of the platform.